# ImportError: No module named 'Crypto' is occuring after installing packages also

Tags: python, python-3.4, importerror, pycrypto

After installing simpleCrypto and PyCrypto in windows... i am getting this error...

steps followed:
cd simplecryto/dist; python setup.py install
cd pycrypto/dist; python setup.py install

test.py:

```
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt

ciphertext = encrypt(password, 'my secret message')
plaintext = decrypt(password, ciphertext)
```

python test.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\simplecrypt\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

Comment: check your installation directory for your module. it seems like you have installed your packages at wrong location

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix that with installing the module through an installer instead of the setup.py. Here's a link to the installer: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/pycrypto26/pycrypto-2.6.win32-py2.7.exe